# How to enable weak-updates with Fedora vanilla kernels (copr)?

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules

I enabled the Fedora vanilla kernel stable (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Kernel_Vanilla_Repositories) for my server.
I compiled a kernel module for a specific kernel version but once it's updated, I have to recompile and recopy the module to the `/lib/modules/...`.

How can I enable the weak-updates feature so that my kernel module is directly linked for each new update?